# What's the issue with this relative paths in webpack.config.js in React JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, file-structure

I have added a `webpack.config.js` for my project. It's like this.

const webpack = require('webpack');

```
var config = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: './public/js/bundle.js'
    }
};

module.exports = config;
```

I tried running project with `npm start` but bundle.js is not generating any content.

File structure is like this.

```
/node_modules
/public
/public/index.html
/public/js/bundle.js
/src/index.js
/src/components
/webpack.config.js
```

Project start in a normal way but bundle.js no content. What would be the issue?

Comment: What does your `npm start` script look like?

Comment: @Tholle 
`"scripts": {
    "webpack": "webpack --mode production",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }`

Comment: Alright. Webpack in development mode, which `react-scripts start` uses, doesn't write files to disk, but instead keeps them all in memory. It's not until you do `npm build` that the files will be written to disk in the `./build` folder.